# _redirects does not work in Netlify for simple HTML app

Tags: url, redirect, netlify

I have an e-commerce site that has closed down. Now I am displaying a message for the customers instead. The message is very simple and consists of a <p> in an index.html file that is hosted on Netlify. I have configured the domain so it displays the new Netlify web site instead of the old site that was hosted elsewhere, and it works as it should. The problem is that the old links that can be found online takes the user to a "Page not found" page. I want the user to be redirected to the main page which displays the message whenever they type anything more in the URL or clicks an old link.

I have created a _redirects file in my project in the same folder (root) as the index.html file is in. In the _redirects file, I have typed

```
/*    /     301!
```

according to the documentation and was expecting all paths to redirect to the main page ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)).  When republishing the project on Netlify, the solution does not work, the user is still taken to a "Not found" page.

This is the repo [Github project](https://github.com/tovehydmark/fridasfina)

Edit: I have now updated the _redirects file to contain specific redirects as such

```
/garner               /                     301!
/rea               /                     301!
/*                /                    301!
```

The pages i have like that are redirected to the main page, however, the /* redirect still does not work.